# Using media queries; Chrome won't adjust CSS grid on window resize, Firefox works just fine. Is it a known issue?

Tags: css, google-chrome, firefox, grid

As per the attached images, there's an extra space above the footer in Chrome (top) while Firefox (bottom) works just fine.

[image: Chrome]

[image: Firefox]

If I refresh Chrome, it behaves, if I resize the window to trigger the next breaking point and then resize it back to the narrow view, the space is there again.

Answer (score 0):

I think that some of your code here would be usefull to help you fix the problem, but I will try some suggestion anyway:

1. Be sure to have this on your  tag in html

```
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1">
```

2. Have you try to do the same test with the chrome developement tool to see if it behave in the same way? You can do it just by clicking on f12, the on this icon [image]. This will allow you to resize window better and also to try your page display in some common device size. Since chrome come with this usefull tool, i think is better to use it instead of manually resize the window.
3. Add screen to you media query syntax:

```
    @media only screen and (min-width: 500px){ ... }
```